# Making an index unique that is technically not unique

Tags: sql-server

I have a 'Messages' table that has the following (relevant to this question) fields:

```
SenderID | int
DateSent | DateTime
```

I was wondering about creating a unique index on those two fields and have a question. Technically, this combination of fields isn't a unique combination (ie by design there's nothing stopping it), however practically it will be. The application that is using this table is a web app and so a sender will never actually be able to send messages immediately after one another due to page refresh time, etc.

Is it acceptable to make this index a unique one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNIQUE` is an index and constraint at the same time. If it has to be unique, than make it unique. If you want just to improve query performance, you can create a non-unique index on 2 fields.

Comment: Surely it does. But if you say `SenderID`+`DateSent` can have duplicates(I'd guess under rare circumstances), and it's acceptable, creating unique index will prevent inserting record that violates unique constraint.

Comment: Theoretically it can be though practically it would be impossible for someone to send 2 messages within a second - ie. after the first message is sent they need to navigate to the "create message" page, fill in at least 50 characters for a valid message, select a recipient and press send before the system even has a chance to create another row.

Answer (score 1):

If you make it unique, and your app runs fast enough, you will get a key violation.

I would not make it unique.

Comment: Surely it's not possible that a web app runs immediately?

Comment: Not "Immediately", but within the resolution of the DateTime column type is very possible. I work with a system that does this exact same this, except the DateTime is limited to a 1 second resolution. It is really annoying when the system runs fast enough to create more than one row per second. Your situation is the same, just on smaller time scale.

Answer (score 0):

What the purpose of making this index unique? I guess including DateSent in the index doesn't reduce your queries time.

Comment: it's being ordered by the DateTime field so I assume it will be reducing it somewhat.

Comment: I see, you're right. You can make a simple index instead of unique in this case